# R visNetwork + igraph weighted network visualization with visEdges

Tags: r, igraph, visnetwork

I have a very simple question regarding combining igraph with visNetwork. I want to weight the edges with visEdges(value=E(graph)$weight), but that does not work.
Here is a toy example to illustrate the problem:

```
     test
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    3    7    1
[2,]    4    0    8    9    5
[3,]   10    3    0    8    3
[4,]    5    1    5    0    7
[5,]    8    2    7    4    0

library(igraph); library(visNetwork)

test.gr <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(test, mode="undirected", weighted=T)
```

If I now try to visualize it as a weighted graph, it doesn't plot it:

```
test.gr %>%
  visIgraph(layout = "layout_in_circle") %>%
  visEdges(value = E(test.gr)$weight)
```

If I use

```
test.gr %>%
  visIgraph(layout = "layout_in_circle") %>%
  visEdges(value = 10)
```

instead, I get a plot:

[image]

but this is of course not what I want. I want different edge widths according to E(test.gr)$weigth.

Can you tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With `visNodes` and `visEdges` you can set **global options** for all nodes and edges. With e.g. `visNodes(shape = "square")`, your make all nodes squares. You understand that this is not the right route to set individual edge widths.

To achieve what you want, you could convert the `igraph` object to a `visNetwork`-list. Then, you could add an 'expected' column with the name "value". `visNetwork` will then use that column to give weight to the edges.

Maybe this is not thé best solution, but it works.

```
test <- as.matrix(read.table(header = FALSE, text = "
    0    1    3    7    1
    4    0    8    9    5
   10    3    0    8    3
    5    1    5    0    7
    8    2    7    4    0"))

library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)

## make igraph object
test.gr <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(test, mode="undirected", weighted=T)

## convert to VisNetwork-list
test.visn <- toVisNetworkData(test.gr)
## copy column "weight" to new column "value" in list "edges"
test.visn$edges$value <- test.visn$edges$weight

test.visn$edges
# from to weight value
#   V1 V2      4     4
#   V1 V3     10    10
#   V1 V4      7     7
#   V1 V5      8     8
#   V2 V3      8     8
#   V2 V4      9     9
#   V2 V5      5     5
#   V3 V4      8     8
#   V3 V5      7     7
#   V4 V5      7     7

visNetwork(test.visn$nodes, test.visn$edges) %>%
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle")
```

This yields the following graph:

[image]

Please, let me know whether this is what you want.

Comment: You saved my life, that's exactly what I was looking for. Definitely, visNetwork should implement this. The edges difference are too heavy by the way. How could we avoid that?